# Detail Table View (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Heyho,

I have an simple Table View with data from a XML-File.
Now I want to show more Information. Therefore I use the method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"test");
}
```

But if I selected an item of the tableView, i got an error:

Tread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x15)

in

```
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Also the NSLog Message isn´t shown.

Hope someone can help. :)

Comment: Use the Breakpoint Navigator to set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions and see if it gives you better information.  (How do you set the delegate for the table view?)

Comment: r u calling didSelectRow method programatically or as per the user..?

Comment: it is called programatically.

Comment: and the tableView is delegate to a TabBarController

Comment: to vishy: it is called when i select an item. This selection code is not my code... in every tutorial you only add this method.

Comment: I found my mistake. I have used "-arc" in Bulid Phases. -.-